# Best structure for tables with more than 10000 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization

I am applying a group of data mining algorithms to a dataset comprised of a set of customers along with a large number of descriptive attributes that summarize various aspects of their past behavior. There are more than 10,000 attributes, each stored as a column in a table with the customer id as the primary key. For several reasons, it is necessary to pre-compute these attributes rather than calculating them on the fly. I generally try to select customer with a specified attribute set. The algorithms can combine any arbitrary number of these attributes together in a single SELECT statement and join the required tables. All the tables have the same number of rows (one per customer).

I am wondering what's the best way to structure these tables of attributes. Is it better to group the attributes into tables of 20-30 columns, requiring more joins on average but fewer columns per SELECT, or have tables with the maximum number of columns to minimize the number of joins, but having potentially all 10K columns joined at once?

I also thought of using one giant 3-column customerID-attribute-value table and storing all the info there, but it would be harder to structure a "select all customers with these attributes-type query that I need."

I'm using MySQL 5.0+, but I assume this is a general SQL-ish question.

Comment: Just to be clear, the primary purpose for these tables is to be queried by a single select statement that returns the IDs of all customers who meet a set of qualifications (hence the attributes) and then join that to a value table to get a value per customer.

Comment: 10,000 columns is much. The SELECT statement will be very long and messy if you wouldn't use `*`.

Comment: The select itself is computer generated, so I don't worry too much about it being long and\or messy.

Comment: Plus, the resulting dataset that is returned to the program is only a single column of integers (the customer IDs).

Answer (score 5):

From my expirience using tables with 10,000 columns is very-very-very bad idea. What if in future this number will be increased?

If there are a lot of attributes you shouldn't use a horizontal scaled tables (with large number of columns). You should create a new table **attributes** and place alltributes values into it. Then connect this table with Many-To-One relationship to main entry table

Maybe the second way is to use no-SQL (like MongoDB) systems

Comment: Well, I am creating a new table **attributes**, but mysql limits it to 3K columns per table (?), so its like **attributes1**, **attributes2**, ... **attributesN**. I'm wondering the best way to distribute tha attributes between these multiple **attributeN** tables.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with No-SQL systems, but I'd rather stick with what I have unless another option has a HUGE benefit. These are not real-time queries so speed is not a primary consideration.

Comment: No, the table **attrubutes** should have 3 columns: cursomerId, attrName, attrValue. Attributes are similar to each other and they are row-like concept (non column-like)

Comment: I thought of that, but I wonder how to write the select statement to return the ids of all the customers that meet a set of criteria tied to the attributes?

Answer (score 2):

As @odiszapc said, you have to use a meta-model structure, like for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(64));
CREATE TABLE customer_attribute(ID INT NOT NULL, ID_CUSTOMER INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(64), VALUE VARCHAR(1024));
```

Return basic informations of given customer:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name='John';
```

Return customer(s) matching certain attributes:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM customer c 
    INNER JOIN attribute a1 ON a1.id_customer = c.id 
                           AND a1.name = 'address' 
                           AND a1.value = '1078, c/ los gatos madrileños'
    INNER JOIN attribute a2 ON a2.id_customer = c.id 
                           AND a2.name = 'age' 
                           AND a2.value = '27'
```

Your generator should generate the inner joins on the fly.

Proper indexes on the tables should allow all this engine to go relatively fast (if we assume 10k attributes per customer, and 10k customers, that's actually pretty much a challenge...)

Comment: That's interesting. I suppose I could have different attribute tables with different data types (numeric vs text data) to allow some comparisons besides equals or not equals. This table will be very large though, 10K attributes, hundreds of thousands of customers certainly, eventually millions. I wonder if it will break down on a desktop server.

Comment: 10^4 attributes x 10^6 customers is a very huge amount of data. This is generally where the limits of database happen and the datamining starts its job. You should investigate and see if some replica-tables couldn't be built by night (offline batchs) according to prevalence of some of your main queries.

Comment: however, it really depends if your queries, the type of information you need about a customer, size of each attribute... If you manage to be concise in your data definition you might perfectly get away with an online system, with a very good hardware, and a very good dba :D

Comment: I think I can squeeze each ID-Attr-Val into 6 bytes if I use a MEDIUMINT-SMALLINT-TINYINT data types. With 100K customers, say I limit it to start at 5K attributes, that's 500M rows taking up about 2.79GB? Seems reasonable from a storage capacity, I just wonder about the performance if you're repeatedly joining a 500M row table, even with indexes... Maybe I'm just paranoid...

Comment: Tough to say. Its a genetic algorithm that chooses its own specificity, so I'd hate to limit it up front to an arbitrary number. Then again, I think I read that MySQL can only join 61 tables together at a time, so as a practical matter, 60 is the most attributes at any one time.

Comment: oh my god!! what kind of values??

Comment: Customer-behavior data, amount of sales in the last 10,30,90,180,365 days, demographic info, etc...

Comment: I don't think this approach (while interesting) would necessarily address my problem either way. I would have to limit the number of attributes stored and\or the number of attributes queried at any given time. Since MySQL allows 4K columns per table, this does not add much additional value with < 4K attributes, and one additional join gets me 4K more.

Answer (score 1):

10,000 columns is much. The SELECT statement will be very long and messy if you wouldn't use `*`. I think you can narrow the attributes down to most useful and meaningful ones, eliminating others

Comment: The select itself is computer generated, so I don't worry too much about it being long and\or messy. I'd certainly like to narrow the attributes down to a smaller set, but my algorithm is designed to find subtle interactions between many attributes, so I need to be able to access them all-together first, so that I can narrow them down. If I knew which ones were important, I wouldn't need the algorithm...

Comment: I mean there may be some columns that are not that important, that can be ignored and not stored/represented in the database